# C# Windows Form SQL Incorrect Syntax near Error for no reason

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

In the code I have, there is a Column I call [Product Name], it is fully defined in my sql server and there should be no problem. This code needs to add the data in TextBox1 to that Column, but I couldn't manage it. I keep getting the error "Incorrect Syntax near [Product Name]" even though I'm pretty sure it's Product Name. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string datatoadd = textBox1.Text;
       try
       {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
           con.Open();
   
               string query = "INSERT INTO fiyat.dbo [Urun Ismi] VALUES (@EklenecekVeri)";
               using (SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(query, baglanti))
               {
                   komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataToAdd" , datatoadd);
                   komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
       baglanti.Close();
           MessageBox.Show("Data added succesfully, added data; ", datatoadd);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error ", ex.Message);
       }
```

I asked my friend for help with this code but he literally did nothing. He said you can use SqlDataReader but I am completely confused.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE. EklenecekVeri and DataToAdd do not match. You must add a parameter for each actually used parameter.

Comment: Firstly, your parameter is named wrong (parameter name in query, and name of adding parameter should have the same name).
Secondly, instead of square brackets '[ ]' use brackets `( )` to define list of column names.
It might be aswell problem with some database stuff like: triggers or indexes, however you given no info about it.

Comment: Missing `.` in `fiyat.dbo [Urun Ismi]` should be `fiyat.dbo.[Urun Ismi]` this assumes that the name of the table is `[Urun Ismi]` you also should specify column names also don't specify the database name, just do `dbo.[Urun Ismi]`. Note also that the connection object needs a `using`.

Comment: First thing to fix, before the code, is the *assumption* that your code is correct. You say there's an error "for no reason" and that "there should be no problem". If you approach the problem with that mindset, you'll look everywhere apart from in your code. There's clearly a parameter naming mismatch here, and others have pointed out issues with the way you're referring to the table. If you'd approached the issue with a mindset of "The problem is *probably* a bug in my code, so I'll look over that really carefully" you might have found at least one or possibly both of those problems.

Comment: Make your life easier and do not create column names with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code might be related to the SQL query syntax. The column name `[Urun Ismi]` should be enclosed in square brackets, and there should be a table name specified after `INSERT INTO`. Also you have define a different parameter(`@EklenecekVeri`) in your query and pass a different one(`@DataToAdd`).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string datatoadd = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "INSERT INTO fiyat.dbo.YourTableName ([Urun Ismi]) VALUES (@DataToAdd)";
            using (SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataToAdd", datatoadd);
                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Data added successfully: " + datatoadd);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```